# How to convert IF function from Excel formula to TSQL?

Tags: sql-server

```
= if( _DataCell_ILF_Cred_ = "", "", 
      _DataCell_ILF_Lyr_Pick * _DataCell_ILF_Cred + _DataCell_Burn_Lyr_Pick_ * (1 - _DataCell_ILF_Cred_) 
    )
```

I want to convert this Excel IF Function into SQL code.

Comment: Which version you have?

Comment: SQL code using what? Variables? Columns in some `select` query? And is this TSQL going to be in a view or a stored procedure or somewhere else? because the language constructs you can use differ between contexts. This is quite unclear. Explaining why you're converting this in the first place would ensure you get a useful answer that isn't just speculation about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` expression, or `IIF()` if you are working on SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN _DataCell_ILF_Cred_ = ',' THEN 
            DoSomething
            END
```

If `_DataCell_ILF_Cred_` <> `','`, it will return `NULL`, if you want to return another value instead of `NULL`, you need to add `ELSE` like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN _DataCell_ILF_Cred_ = ',' THEN 
                DoSomething
                ELSE
                DoSomethingElse
                END
```

However, your the last part of your if is not clear, you need to provide more information (as datatypes) to get better answer.

Comment: If the place they're doing the conversion is an SP, then they could also use `if`/`else`, but it's very unclear where they want this code to end up, and set-based solutions are preferable to procedural ones anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Literal translation (with some mock data) would be as follows:

```
select 
1 as '_DataCell_ILF_Cred_',
2 as '_DataCell_ILF_Lyr_Pick',
3 as '_DataCell_Burn_Lyr_Pick'
into #test

select * from #test

declare @_DataCell_ILF_Cred_ decimal
if ((select [_DataCell_ILF_Cred_] from #test) <> '')
begin
    select @_DataCell_ILF_Cred_ = [_DataCell_ILF_Lyr_Pick] * [_DataCell_ILF_Cred_]
                                + [_DataCell_Burn_Lyr_Pick] * (1 -[_DataCell_ILF_Cred_]) 
                                from #test
    select @_DataCell_ILF_Cred_ as [_DataCell_ILF_Cred_]
end
```

Do not hesitate to check IF...ELSE documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql